# Create horizontal Treeview Control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, treeview, asp.net-controls

Hi all of you knowledgeable folk, 
I am a Jr developer, so bear with me as I try to make sense.

I recently received a client requirement that requires a sort of "menu", if you will, of items with checkboxes.

3 of the 4 master tree nodes would have subnodes. All nodes will have checkboxes. Unchecking/checking the parent of a node would affect all children.

[Vertical Treeview with Checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvzsc.png)

I've got half of what I want -- however, I need this data to be displayed **horizontally**.

Is there any way for me orient the treeview horizontally, possibly through a custom control? I've been prowling the web for days and can't find a plausible solution using the TreeView control itself. The menu control is close to what I want but I haven't been able to tweak it to suit my needs, and I can't use an organizational chart.

All feedback is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: It's confusing what you mean by display horizontally.  How would you indicate the parent/child relationship of a TreeView in a horizontal orientation?  Would the parent be above the children?

Comment: @seano666 That's the only design that makes sense. There would never be any grandchildren so I wouldn't have to worry about design issues there.